# SQL Left Join on more then 5 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

The code is retreating what I want it to retrieve, though it does 4 times more that I need.

I have a table called **property** with a **PK property_ID**. A property has a **title**, **short description**, **long description** and it **belongs to a point of interest**, which in turn is connected to a city. Title, short&long description have all independent link tables, in which a link is created between a property and the corresponding translation in the translation table.
I am using left joins to collect all the desired information, below in the image attachment you can see the results.

[image]

The desired result would be that it would return **only 2 rows**, with the corresponding translation of the title, short and long description. At the moment is **returning 8 rows**.

The issue that I noticed is it orders the columns in a weird way. 
If you look closer, you can notice that **title** and **titleLangCode** are ordered correctly after **titleLangCode**, while long and short descriptions are ordered by their own **langCode**. Grouping them wont work since they are ordered differently, so ordering them has no effect, union didn´t work either because of the column numbers, even tried distinct but with no avail.

The code:

```
               select 
                    property.*,
                    title_translation.title,
                    title_translation.langCode as titleLangCode,
                    short_desc_translation.shortDescription,
                    long_desc_translation.longDescription,
                    short_desc_translation.langCode as shortLangCode,
                    long_desc_translation.langCode as longLangCode,
                    property_city_poi.city_poi_link_ID
                from 
                    property
                left join
                    title_link
                on
                    property.property_ID = title_link.property_ID
                left join
                    title_translation
                on
                    title_link.title_link_ID = title_translation.title_link_ID
                left join
                    short_desc_link
                on
                    property.property_ID = short_desc_link.property_ID
                left join
                    short_desc_translation
                on
                    short_desc_link.short_desc_link_ID = short_desc_translation.short_desc_link_ID
                left join
                    long_desc_link
                on
                    property.property_ID = long_desc_link.property_ID
                left join
                    long_desc_translation
                on
                    long_desc_link.long_desc_link_ID = long_desc_translation.long_desc_link_ID  
                left join 
                    property_city_poi
                on  
                    property.property_ID = property_city_poi.property_ID
                where
                    property.property_ID = 10
```

Is there a possibility of somehow combing limit with group ? I tried but have not succeed.

```
title_link
  title_link_ID
  property_ID
  dateCreated

title_translation
  title_translation_ID
  title_link_ID
  langCode
  title

short_desc_link
  short_desc_link_ID
  property_ID
  dateCreated

short_desc_translation
  short_desc_translation_ID
  short_desc_link_ID
  langCode
  shortDescription

long_desc_link
  long_desc_link_ID
  property_ID
  dateCreated

long_desc_translation
  long_desc_translation_ID
  long_desc_link_ID
  langCode
  shortDescription
```

Comment: Could you provide format data instead of image?thanks

Comment: @D-Shih Sorry, but what do you mean with format data ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, the issue is that you have multiple translation tables which have a 1 to many relationship to the property. So after the first join you have 2 rows then 4 and then 8 with all combinations of languages.

You can limit this by joining on 2 conditions.

```
... property p
INNER JOIN titel_link tl on p.id = tl.propertyid
INNER JOIN short_desk_link sdl on p.id = tl.propertyid AND tl.langCode = sdl.langCode
```

I've simplified this a little and used aliases for table names to shorten the join conditions.

Edit: I'd say this is also a sign of bad database design. you should probably introduce a table 'language' and then a mapping table property-translation mapping. Not sure if this is under your control but a setup with tables like this would be better.

- Property: all the details for the property.
- Language: A listing of all the languages with Id.
- FieldId: A list of named columns that you have in your database.
- Translation: A combination of Property, Language and Field on which you can then have a single translation for that field.

Comment: I have updated the post with my table structure. I understand what you explained about the table is it seems to be a reasonable reason to have a extra table with the language list. Though I tried to simulate your code by writing(following your example): AND (tl.langCode = "pt" or tl.langCode = "en"). And this has not worked either.

Comment: what happens is that you need to join both to match the property id, but the moment you join the second translation table you need to make sure you only join same language to same language. `property.id = langatable2.propertyIdAND langtable1.lang = langtable2.lang`